# Periodicity in Galois Cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, etale-cohomology

Let $k$ be a field which is not of characteristic $\ell$ and $\nu \geq 1$. Suppose for a moment that $\ell$ is *odd*. Even without $\ell$-th roots of $1$, then we have isomorphisms $H^*_{et}(k, \mu_{\ell^{\nu}}^{\otimes i}) \simeq H^*_{et}(k, \mu_{\ell^{\nu}}^{\otimes i+(\ell-1)(\ell^{\nu-1})})$ for all $i \in \mathbb{Z}$. This boils down to the fact that the Galois group of $k(\mu_{\ell^{\nu}})/k$ is injects into the units of $\mathbb{Z}/\ell^{\nu}$.

When $\ell^{\nu}$ is even, the Galois group is not cyclic except for $\nu=1,2$.

What is the analogue of such "periodicity" for this case?

Comment: I have a question regarding your notation, does $\mu_{l^v}^{\otimes r}$ stands for: $Gal(\bar{k}/k)$ acts on $\mathbb{Z}/l^v$ by $\chi^r$ where $\chi$ is the "cyclotomic characeter": $\chi:  Gal(\bar{k}/k) \to (\mathbb{Z}/l^v)^{\times}$? If this is what you meant then the above statement is also true for $l$ is even because $\chi^{(l-1)l^{v-1}}=1$.

Comment: In the case $\ell=2$, $v \geq 3$, one can take the exponent $\ell^{v-2}$ for the same reason.